# Odoo Connection Error to PostgreSQL remote host

Tags: postgresql, odoo, ubuntu-16.04, odoo-9, postgresql-9.5

I am using Odoo 9 and PostgreSQL 9.5, when  i want to connect the Odoo with remote PostgreSQL Server i get the following error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

It is good to mention that i can connect to the remote host using psql in bash smoothly. the only issue is that Odoo 9 can not connect to it. here is the configuration file parameters of Odoo. is there anything that I am missing.

```
db_host = 172.30.30.157
db_name = somedatabase
db_port = 5432
db_user = someuser
db_password = 123@Abc
```

Comment: Is the user existing in postgres? Is this user allowed to connect from outside (hba conf)?

Comment: yes all the configurations in PostgreSQL are right, i can connect using openERP (7) with the same PostgreSQL configuration. the issue is with Odoo 9.

Comment: So in your shell you can connect from the same host using the exact same password and user to the exact same db?

Comment: Try hardcoding the db parameters into your startup script (shot in the dark), like this. `--db_user someuser --db_password 123@abc --db_host 172.30.30.157 --db_port 5432`

Comment: I have heard rumblings on forums regarding config file parameters that dont act as you might expect. You might want to check your logs to determine if odoo is really trying to establish the remote connection or is it just trying to connect locally. If you dont see any logging to indicate one way or another you could simply restore the same db on your odoo server and see if it just works, which would be an indication it was never trying to use the remote connection.

Comment: Which could atleast tell you whether it is firewall or hba.conf on your remote or if it is simply odoo not honouring your config.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :)